# derivative of the laplacian operator

Tags: derivatives, laplacian

Assumes $\Delta \phi = \nabla\cdot\nabla\phi$ and
$$
f(\phi) = \Delta\phi
$$
then, what is
$$
\frac{df(\phi)}{d\phi}
$$

no clue how to solve this

Comment: Taking derivative w.r.t. a function, i.e. a functional derivative?

Comment: The operator $\phi \mapsto \triangle \phi$ is linear, so its derivative is itself.

Answer (score 0):

In a rough sense, if you are taking a functional derivative, you can see $\Delta \phi$ as an infinite dimensional matrix multiplied to the vector space of functions, so the result is a constant matrix $\Delta$.