Partial derivative in time-dependent Schrodinger equation
I am looking at the time-dependent Schrodinger equation with respect to the following:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k} -\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{1}{k}\nabla^2+V(k,t) $$
It is my understanding that the derivative of the Laplacian is just the Laplacian, so I would need to treat $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{1}{k}\nabla^2$ under the product rule of two terms after removing constants.
Then I think the derivative is:
$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{1}{k^2}\nabla^2 + \frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{1}{k}\nabla^2 + V(1,0)$$
Is this correct?

I am assuming you are differentiating an operator that depends on the parameter $k$ with respect to $k$ itself. You should put brackets around the Schrödinger operator after $\frac{\partial}{\partial k}$ then, otherwise the question is unreadable. The derivative of the Laplacian is zero, if $k$ is just some parameter. Why are you evaluating $V$ at $k=1,t=0$?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961788/derivative-of-the-laplacian-operator
says derivative of the laplacian is the laplacian

The derivative of the Laplacian as a functional of its input argument is the Laplacian itself. That is, $\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi} \Delta( \phi)\cdot\psi=\Delta\psi$. If you differentiate the Laplacian with respect to a parameter that has nothing to do with it, the derivative is zero.

so factor out constant $\frac{\hbar^2}{2}$ and get $\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{1}{k^2}\nabla^2$  ?

The derivative of the Schrödinger operator $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{1}{k}\nabla^2+V(k,t)$ with respect to the parameter $k$ is
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial k} \left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{1}{k}\nabla^2+V(k,t)\right]= \frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{1}{k^2}\nabla^2+\frac{d V}{dk} (k,t). $$
Is this what you want?

yes, more or less!
I thought the solution would be negative though...

can I factor out $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2}$ so that the solution is negative?

i'll mark this as the answer, but need the solution to be negative if possible

I don’t understand what you mean. There is one solution only. If you want to write it in a different way you can, but it is always the same object. In which sense do you want it to be negative, and why?

sorry, I followed your derivation and realized it'd be a negative times a negative either way....
Thank you so much!
